# Angular 2 Create Observable to return local stored data

Tags: angularjs, angular, return, observable

I´m fairly new to angular 2 and i have a little Problem and I didn´t find another thread which really descriebs my problem and has a solution for this...

To start with, i have a service, which manages data (epgService).
I have a second service, which loads data from database (apiService) and returns data as Observable.
And I have a component, whicht wants data.

Now the component asks the epgService (service 1) to get some data.
Then the epgService checks, if the data is actually loaded from server and is "cached" internally. It it is not, it asks the apiService to load the data.

My Problem: I do not know, how i can return an Observable from epgService to the component.
In the epgService i a a variable to store the data. If the data is there, the variable get filled. If not, the data is loaded from apiService as Observable, then the data of the observable stored in the local variable.
Afterwards, at the end of the service, i want to return the local variable as Observable.
How can i do this?

Here´s the code:

epgService:

```
getEPGbyChannel(channelID, mydate) {
        let epg: EPG = this.variables.getEPG();
        // local variable to store the data which then should be returned
        let returnEPG;
        // check if epg is there
        for (let channel of epg.epg) {
            if (channel.channelId === channelID) {
                for (let date of channel.dates) {
                    if (date === mydate) {
                       console.log("yeah, epg is there :)");
                       // return EPG
                       returnEPG = date;
                       return returnEPG.asObservable();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // load epg from database, because its not there
        if (!returnEPG) {
            console.log("epg is not there :(");
            let fromDate = new Date(mydate.getFullYear(), mydate.getMonth(), mydate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0);
            let endDate = new Date(mydate.getFullYear(), mydate.getMonth(), mydate.getDate(), 23, 59, 59);
            this.apiService.getChannelEPGbyTime(channelID, fromDate, endDate).
                subscribe(
                data => {
                    if (data.programme) {
                        console.log("got epg:");
                        console.log(data.programme);
                        // write data from observable in local variable
                        returnEPG = this.formatter.formatChannelEPG(data.programme);
                        return returnEPG.asObservable();
                    } else {
                        console.log("epg doesn´t exist on server");
                        returnEPG = "no epg";
                        return returnEPG.asObservable();
                    }
                });
        }
    }
```

Component:

```
this.epgService.getEPGbyChannel(channel.EPGID, date).
                subscribe(
                data => {
                    console.log("data!!!");
                    console.log(data);
                },
                //error => this.error = <any>error,
                error => {
                    this.variables.setFailure("Das EPG konnte nicht geladen werden.");
                    this.loading = false;
                });
```

The return value here is 'returnEPG is undefined'.
Can someone provide me a solution?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Even if your code goes into the if block, by the time you make your `getChannelEPGbyTime` and execute its callback, you will already return the `returnEPG.asObservable();` since `getChannelEPGbyTime` is async. Thus, you return an empty observable.

Comment: mh, ok, makes sense...
To i have to return the data directly in the two cases: If the data is found locally i have to return as observable and if the data is loaded from epg? Do you have a possible solution?

Comment: Write an `else` case and return `returnEPG.asObservable();` there. And in the if case return something too :-) I'd prefer to return the observable and handle the logic inside the caller's callback.

Comment: I have updated my service...
But this give me this failure: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.epgService.getEPGbyChannel(...) is undefined

Comment: If you don't return something in the if block that might happen. Can you include the full error tho?

Comment: Ups, i forgot somehting, edited again.
Here´s the failure: 
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.epgService.getEPGbyChannel(...) is undefined
Unhandled Promise rejection: this.epgService.getEPGbyChannel(...) is undefined ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: this.epgService.getEPGbyChannel(...) is undefined
Stack-Trace:
[object Object] TimelineComponent.prototype.getEPGbyGroup@http://localhost:3000/app/components/timeline/timeline.component.js:64:9

Comment: You are providing `epgService` in the consturctor of the component that you are using right?

Comment: yes. Here´s the constructor: constructor(private router: Router, private variables: Variables, private apiService: ApiService, private formatter: Formatter, private helperService: HelperService, private timerService: TimerService, private epgService: EPGService)

I think the return value is wrong. Maybe it´s not an observable i can subscribe to, but i do not know the solution :/

Comment: Well also if returnEPG is defined, you aren't returning anything :/ and as I've mentioned I'd prefer to return the observable and handle the logic inside the caller's callback but maybe someone will come up with a better answer

Comment: ok, but even if i would return the observable, what will happen, if the data is stored locally (--> so in the epgService i do not have an observable)?
Then i have to return a new observable, too...